XSL FO Adding content in the table cell right align with preceding dots (if space exist before content)
Need to align content to the right side of the cell.
If space exist in the cell need to populate with dots
Hello Welcome to Stackoverflow
......Welcome to Stackoverflow
................ Stacloverflow
.................iiiiiiiiiiiii
.................WWWWWWWWWWWWW

Constraints

If content is overflowing need to hide (overflow="hidden")
Content must be right aligned

Note:

tried with length of the string, but on real values all characters not occupying similar space ('W' takes double space compared to 'i')
Sample code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


       <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fo">




<xsl:variable name="thinBorder">1pt solid grey</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="taskBorder">0.5pt dotted grey</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="labelFontSize">7pt</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="labelFontWeight">bold</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="dataFontSize">8pt</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="margin">2px</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="taskMargin">10pt</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="tableHeaderMarginTop">5px</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="tableHeaderMarginBottom">1px</xsl:variable>


<!-- ================================================================== -->
<!-- Base template                                                      -->
<!-- ================================================================== -->
<xsl:template match="stxx/form">
    <pageSize>
        <page-width>21.59cm</page-width>
        <page-height>28.30cm</page-height>
    </pageSize>
    <headerMargins>
        <extent>1cm</extent>
    </headerMargins>
    <pageHeader>
            <xsl:call-template name="report-header" />
    </pageHeader>
    <bodyMargins>   
        <marginTop>5.7cm</marginTop>
        <marginBottom>3cm</marginBottom>
    </bodyMargins>
    
    <middle>
        <fo-content>
            
        </fo-content>
    </middle>
    <footerMargins>
        <extent>2cm</extent>
    </footerMargins>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
    
</xsl:template>



<!-- ================================================================== -->
<!-- Template for Header                                                -->
<!-- ================================================================== -->
<xsl:template name="report-header">
    
    <fo:table font-size="{$dataFontSize}">
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block text-align="left" margin-left="45pt">
                        A/C <fo:inline font-weight="bold">7LP</fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right" margin-right="23pt">
                        Page
                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><fo:page-number/></fo:inline> of 
                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page"/></fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
    
    <fo:table border="solid 0.5mm black" text-align="left" table-layout="fixed" width="88.5%" font-size="{$dataFontSize}" margin-left="15.85mm">
        <fo:table-body start-indent="0" end-indent="0">
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table margin-top="6px">
                        <fo:table-column column-width="10%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="36%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="5%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="16%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="30%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="3%"/>
                        
                        <fo:table-body start-indent="0" end-indent="0">
                            <fo:table-row margin-left="1px" height="30px">
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block margin-left="{$margin}" margin-top="{$margin}" font-weight="{$labelFontWeight}" font-size="{$labelFontSize}">
                                            Serial Number:
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" height="20px">
                                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="1 to 10">...</xsl:for-each>73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-503573-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035 73-0500-8-5035
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block margin-left="{$margin}" margin-top="{$margin}" font-weight="{$labelFontWeight}" font-size="{$labelFontSize}">
                                        Serial Number:
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden">
                                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="1 to 200">...</xsl:for-each>7302
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="17%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="80%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="3%"/>
                        
                        <fo:table-body start-indent="0" end-indent="0">
                            <fo:table-row margin-left="1px" height="30px">
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block margin-left="{$margin}" margin-top="{$margin}" font-weight="{$labelFontWeight}" font-size="{$labelFontSize}">
                                        Description:
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden">
                                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="1 to 40">...</xsl:for-each> CKC, ST25, 777-300, ST025 PKG
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="6%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="40%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="5%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="14%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="32%"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="3%"/>
                        
                        <fo:table-body start-indent="0" end-indent="0">
                            <fo:table-row margin-left="1px" height="30px">
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block margin-left="{$margin}" margin-top="{$margin}" font-weight="{$labelFontWeight}" font-size="{$labelFontSize}">
                                            Test:
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden">
                                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="1 to 100">...</xsl:for-each>X 
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block margin-left="{$margin}" margin-top="{$margin}" font-weight="{$labelFontWeight}" font-size="{$labelFontSize}">
                                        Test Description:
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden">
                                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="1 to 20">...</xsl:for-each>N/A 
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                    
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Well, at least show us your current XSL-FO, not only some screenshots.

@MartinHonnen done

Another screenshot, really? Consider to post code as text so that anyone wanting to answer can copy snippets into the answer and edit in any suggestions to change the code to your requirements.

@MartinHonnen added code now

@MartinHonnen could you give any idea

You got an answer, use that suggestion. Tony knows XSL-FO much better than I.

Can you show the snippet of XSL-FO corresponding to your formatted sample?  We don't have your data to be able to run the stylesheet anyway.

Use fo:leader, which can make a sequence of dots to fill the available space on the current line. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_leader)

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/78673746/4092205:
For discussion on how to use fo:leader, see the examples at https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.leader-expansion and the fo:leader samples from the XSL-FO Samples Collection at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples. Particularly see https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples#axf-last-right-justify-1, with PDF at https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/line/axf-last-right-justify-1.pdf?hsLang=en. The fo:block-container sample from that is:
<fo:block-container text-align="justify" text-align-last="right">
<fo:block>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing cons equat elit...
<fo:leader />
<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%" />
<fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">Antenna House</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>


looks like leader not coming and text overlapping

suggest any changes

added code snippet to question
